# I'm struggling to create a unit test, if someone could please have a look on my code to figure out the possible issue:

Tags: unit-testing, python-unittest

The code below is supposed to simulate a ATM, I have to create 5 unit tests for the code, and to be honest I have no idea why it is not working! :(
It should show on the Terminal that ran 5 tests in x s, however it keeps saying that Ran 0 tests and OK. Should I import a library? Any suggestion?

```
import unittest

def withdraw(wdra):
    balanace_account = 100
    if wdra < balanace_account:
        balanace_account -= wdra
        return balanace_account


class AtmTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def correct_amount(self):
        expected = 29.50 #withdraw de 70.50
        result = withdraw(70.5)
        self.assertEqual(expected,result)

    def invalid_error(self):
        expected = 1
        result = withdraw(1/0)
        self.assertEqual(expected, result)

    def incorrect_amount(self):
        expected = 50.00
        result = withdraw(60)
        self.assertEqual(expected,result)

    def greater_withdraw(self):
        expected = -10
        result = withdraw(110)
        self.assertEqual(expected,result)

    def invalid_data_type(selfS):
        expected = 100
        result = withdraw('0')
        self.assertEqual(expected, result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()


    pass
```

Comment: What terminal command did you use to run the test?

Answer (score 0):

You should name your test methods with `test` prefix so that the test runner can identify test methods. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#basic-example) for example.